UART between TMC2208 and Ardurino : unable to use read from TMC
LT, DR:
I can program the TMC via UART but can't read anything back, and I don't like it :'(

Description
I want to make my ardurino UNO communique with a TMC2208-V3.0 (manual). The use case is to control a nema17 stepper motor.
Note on the hardware
I know TMC2208-V3.0 may come in different version, mine is "Kingprint TMC2208 V3.0-UART Stepper" the documentation said I shouldn't need any modification, and I can see a resistor here so OK. 
In the "Kingprint TMC2208 V3.0-UART Stepper" the label spacing is weird for the pnd and uart pin but it's most likely a typo. So the layout is:

Why did I plug a motor if my question is about UART and TMC2208
I ran into a problem where I can send UART communication but not receive it (form the pov of the ardurino) so I need the motor to see the impact of my communication.
Additional note you may need to wire the TMC2208 in a different way if you don't use a motor.
 (source)
How to check?
Without UART communcation when I rotate the motor without changing the micro stepping, it's kinda slow. If I speed it up without changing the target speed it mean I have lowered the micro stepping via UART, this part is working! And if I can read the new micro stepping it mean I have a bi-directional UART communication. Well, for now, I don't have it.
Working: Programming the TMC2208 (one way UART communication)
Wiring

simulate this circuit – Schematic created using CircuitLab
Why I don't use Rx/Tx pin from the ardurino?
When I use the hardware Rx/Tx there is interference (weird characters in the display) with the Serial.print. To limit the side effect I decided to not use them.
The SoftwareSerial used by the TMC2208Stepper allow us to simulate the Rx/Tx pin with any unreserved pin.

Code
Full code
It's the code I try to run in both Tx only and Tx/Rx experiments.
#include <Arduino.h>
#include <TMCStepper.h> // will use SoftwareSerial.h
#include <AccelStepper.h>

// because I am lazy AF
template <class... T>
void print(T... args)
{
    (Serial.print(args), ...);
    Serial.println("");
}

constexpr int   uart_pin_rx = 7;    // blue
constexpr int   uart_pin_tx = 8;    // white + 1K oh
constexpr float RS          = 0.11; // from spec
TMC2208Stepper  driver(uart_pin_rx, uart_pin_tx, RS);

constexpr int dir_pin  = 10; // blue
constexpr int step_pin = 11; // brown
AccelStepper  stepper(AccelStepper::DRIVER, step_pin, dir_pin);

void setup()
{
    Serial.begin(9600);
    driver.beginSerial(115200);

    driver.pdn_disable(1);      // Use PDN/UART pin for communication
    driver.mstep_reg_select(1); // use the register for micro steping, not the wiring MS1/2
    driver.I_scale_analog(0);   // Adjust current from the registers

    driver.microsteps(0);    // 0 => no micro steping => fast boi
    driver.rms_current(600); // Set motor RMS current

    print("Start. enable : ", driver.isEnabled(), " enn : ", driver.enn(), " toff : ", driver.toff());

    // hoping get some information back
    uint8_t  version    = driver.version();
    uint16_t microsteps = driver.microsteps();

    if (version == 0x00 || version == 0xFF)
    {
        print("Fail : version == ", version);
        print("Microsteps: ", microsteps);
    }
    else
    {
        print("Version of TMC2208: ", version);
        print("Microsteps: ", microsteps);
    }

    // make the motor run
    stepper.setMaxSpeed(1000);
    stepper.setAcceleration(900);
    stepper.moveTo(1000000);
}

void loop()
{
    stepper.run();
}


Output
without surprise, we can't read from the TMC2208 and we got:
Start. enable : 0 enn : 0 toff : 0
Fail : version == 0
Microsteps: 256


How I choose the RS value?
The Rs 0.11 is given by the spec.


Not Working: reading information from the TMC2208
In this part I will detail what I try and my understanding of why it fail (if any).
Trying to only read from the TMC2208
Motivation: If I can only write, can I only read ?
Modification: swap the blue cable from pin 8 Tx to pin 7 Rx
Result: Nothing, the motor spin slowly (since no more 0 micro steeping) and same display Fail : version == 0, Microsteps: 256
Interpretation: My guess is, to read a register we need to send a message like "hey! what's in this register?" and get a response "it's 3". Since I can't sent anything, well it does not work.

1. Just plug both pin Rx/Tx to UART
Motivation: The soft call SSwitch::active() which switch the activated pin, so there shouldn't be any conflict
Modification:

plug both pin Rx/Tx to UART
bonus: add a pull up (or pull down) resistor

Result:

Tx ok (motor fast)
Rx KO (with or with out pull up/down)

Interpretation: No idea, look legit to me.

2. Plug both pin Rx/Tx to UART but add resistor to Tx line
Motivation: solution proposed by @Jens and match (this doc)
Modification:

simulate this circuit

plug Rx to UART and Tx with 1k resistor to UART.
bonus: add a pull up (or pull down) resistor.

Result:

without pull up/down : Tx ok (motor fast) Rx KO
with pull up/down : Tx KO (motor slow) Rx KO

Interpretation:

without pull up/down : No idea, look legit to me.
with pull up/down : the 1k ohm in the Tx is the same as my pull up/down so Tx signal cannot overcome the pull up/down, and it's fail.


3. Using an discrete open-drain buffer
Motivation: solution proposed by @Rudy Bnch and more detailed in this article.
Modification:

simulate this circuit
the schematic use a different schema for 2N7000 than the article.
 (source)
Result:

Tx KO the motor run even slower than before!
Rx KO
The TMC draw 1.1A, the max I have set on my generator. There is no short circuit on the generator side.
Same result with Rx unplug

Interpretation:

I am lost. I have check several time the wiring (and even made it a second time)


Ending words
I am new to electronics so I may have missed some obvious stuff.
I would like to thanks @Rudy Bnch for his patience and support.
If you need more infos, please let me know!

Ive have the exact same problem you faced but I am using a CNC shield v3 on my arduino. I have the same TMC2208 as you and there is also a resistor on mine. Did you end up figuring out how to make it work? I cant even get just the tx signal to work.

Sadly I have only the one way UART communication arduino -> TMC working (describe in the "Working" part).
Good luck with your debugging and if you found some thing pls come back and tell us!

You need separate pins for TX and RX using the software serial library, because this library cannot disable the TX output during idle and does not implement an open drain tx driving mode, which would absolutely be possible with the hardware.
So the stepper module cannot override the always active Arduino TX signal.
You need a resistor of typically 1 kΩ between the TX output pin and the connection of RX pin and UART pin of the module. This way the module can override the TX signal level of the Arduino while sending data.

Thank you for your answer, I try what you suggest without success. I have update my post in the "edit 1" part to show what I have done. If it does not match what you describe, please tell me.

Driver's PDN_UART pin

I am 80% sure that the UART pin is the 4th from the bottom left, but the label are not align in the spec, maybe a typo.

Yes, if you are looking from the bottom side of the driver it will be the 4th from the bottom left. But looking from the top side (as shown on your first picture) it is the 4th from the bottom right.
ARDUINO UNO R3 UART pins
On your schematic, you are using pins 7 and 8 of your Arduino as RX and TX.
But the Arduino Uno R3 datasheet shows two different pin numbering:

One for the digital I/Os
One for the analog I/Os

(source: Arduino UNO R3 datasheet, page 10)
And it appears that, on the analog part, pin 7 is a ground (GND) connection, and pin 8 is a power connection for an input voltage. So you really should not use these for a digital communication.
Looking at the Arduino documentation, we find that the default pins for UART communication are the pins named D0 (for RX) and D1 (for TX). (Source: Arduino UART, section "Arduino UART pins")
So you should use these two pins for your UART communication.
1-Wire UART
Your driver provides a single connection for the UART communication.
By looking at the TMC2208 datasheet you can proceed by two means :

TX-only communication (simplest, but dangerous)
Half-duplex communication (more complex)

To implement the TX only communication, you just need to connect your arduino's TX pin to PDN_UART, RX remains unconnected. In this way, you can configure your driver by sending write commands only. The driver sends data back only if a read command was sent first. But be careful, sending a read command or an unexpected driver response in this configuration may damage your arduino or your driver.
To be able to protect your devices and send read/write commands to the driver and receive data back, you need the half-duplex communication, and will have to create an integrated or discrete open-drain buffer:

With the VPUP being your +5V, you can use This part for the nmos.
This is due to the fact that your arduino has push-pull outputs whereas 1-wire devices have an open-drain output (Source: Using a UART to Implement a 1-Wire Bus Master), if you want to understand these concepts you will have to do some research about digital output topologies, transistors and high impedance state.
However, in the chapter 4.3 of the TMC2208 datasheet There is the following figure :

This chapter does not give information about the conditions for this configuration to work but it can be easily implemented so you can try that too.
I really recommend you to implement the TX-only communication first. This configuration is enough to write commands to the driver's registers and therefore set the microsteps parameter as you wish.
Once you succeded in this, you should implement one of the half-duplex configurations (I suggest the simplest, the 1kohm between lines solution) which will protect your devices from unexpected response from the driver.
Be careful not every registers are writable and readable, you can check the registers' parameters by looking at the Chapter 5 "Register Map" of the TMC2208 datasheet.
TMCStepper library
To initialize your driver and the UART communication you should take a look at this exemple from the library's github: TMCStepper.h simple config
This exemple shows a simple configuration to initialize the driver, the UART communication, and run the motor in alternating directions.
This file shows several definition and initialization commands because it covers multiple version of these drivers such as TMC2130, TMC2660, TMC5160... and of course TMC2208.
So you should try to identify the right configuration for your driver by uncommenting the useful lines and commenting the unuseful ones.
Since you are using a "Software Serial" and not a "Hardware Serial" you should comment this line :
TMC2208Stepper driver(&SERIAL_PORT, R_SENSE);
And uncomment this line : //TMC2208Stepper driver(SW_RX, SW_TX, R_SENSE);
Also, some comments after the line #define R_SENSE 0.11f explains what this "R_SENSE" value should be (the RS you are talking about at the end of your question) depending on the driver you are using. After my research, I think you are using a "SilentStepStick" series, so the right value may be 0.11.
With enough trial and error, you should be able to make this work.
Good luck.

Thank you for your answer, the note is kinda hard for me, I will need some time to go through

Thx for the update, I have fix the driver.begin into driver.beginSerial, the RS at 0.11 and I have wired back my motor (to be sure). For the pullup on Rx I have try 5.1Kohm and 4 1kohm in series. But still no UART communication. In your last update you mention hardware that I don't have (like NC7WZ07) there is no way to make it works without extra hardware ? (btw, the motor run just fine, just the UART part doesn't)

I have burn my ardurino do to a messy bread bord short circuit :/. I guess I will buy the component with the ardurino replacement \o/

when I look at TMC2208Stepper::begin() code, it call  beginSerial(115200) so calling begin() after beginSerial will only override it, isn't it ? https://github.com/teemuatlut/TMCStepper/blob/74e8e6881adc9241c2e626071e7328d7652f361a/src/source/TMC2208Stepper.cpp#L52

I have 0 knowledge about nmos and hard time finding 2n7002 without 2 week of shiping. Can I use any N-channel mosfet with mA and V that look ok ? the 2N7000 seem close enough (little less mA)

Nice, I just receive every thing and starting re-working on it! (with a cleaner cable management, no more short!)

Breaking news : If I add driver.mstep_reg_select(1);    driver.pdn_disable(1); I can change the micro stepping of the motor, even if I still cannot read anything from the uart. So the Tx works but not the Rx

This is what is done in the driver.begin method, but yeah it looks like you succeeded in using the TX only communication, which is the easiest way to use the UART communication and configure your driver. Good job.

"And it appears that, on the analog part, pin 7 is a ground (GND) connection, and pin 8 is a power connection for an input voltage. So you really should not use these for a digital communication." I don't use those, they are labeled as A0..A5 or "ground", "5v" and so on. I use the Digital pin.
For what I understand I don't have to use RT/TX (pin 0/1) of the board since the library SoftwareSerial is used by the driver, but I will retry with those

Alright if you used digital pins of your arduino and it works, you don't need to change those. I was saying this because the numbering you are using in your picture can be confusing since there are two numbering, one for the analog pins and one for the digital pins.

My bounty was for drawing attention, so I gave it :)
I don't mark as resolve since I still need some work to have the UART working in half duplex but I hope I will have it working soon

Thanks ! Feel free to ask if you have any doubts, although I think the hardware part is well covered now.

I have update my post so it better show what I have tried, If you have any feed back feel free !
